# Same code but I can't recive GET parameter

Tags: laravel

I made a contact form which works perfect I could receive GET parameter
About another project, I use same program code and add couple of JS file after that
I couldn't receive GET parameter. I don't think JS file affect it...
Could you teach me why I can't receive GET parameter please?

UPDATE ERROR CODE

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'pid' doesn't have a
> default value

Here is my URL:

https://test11223344556677.com/test/public/contact?pid=d2D4B3j2D8Xf3

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Contact;
    use Mail;
    
    class ContactUsFormController extends Controller {
    
        // Create Contact Form
        public function createForm(Request $request) {
          return view('contact');
        }
    
        // Store Contact Form data
        public function ContactUsForm(Request $request) {
    
            // Form validation
            $this->validate($request, [
              'name' => 'required',
              'phone' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:10',
             ]);       
            //  Get ip
            $request['ip'] = $request->ip();
            //  Get User-Agent
            $request['ua'] = $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
            //  Store data in database
            Contact::create($request->all());
    
            //  Send mail to admin
            \Mail::send('mail', array(
    
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
                'pid' => $request->get('pid'),
    
            ), function($message) use ($request){
                $message->from($request->email);
                $message->to('mymail@mymail.site', 'title')->bcc('mail2@mail2.site')->subject($request->get('title2'));
            });
    
            return back()->with('success', 'thank you');
        }
    
    }
```

web.php

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    
    // Render in view
    Route::get('/contact', [
        'uses' => 'ContactUsFormController@createForm'
    ]);
    
    // Post form data
    Route::post('/contact', [
        'uses' => 'ContactUsFormController@ContactUsForm',
        'as' => 'contact.store'
    ]);
```

UPDATE
with Dear STA taught me this code
`$data['pid'] = $request->pid ?? 'default value';`

[image]

If I don't use above code I couldn't get pid value.
Take a look below image. pid is gone
[image]

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Thank you for comment. sorry I post my error message.

Comment: Use `$request->pid` instead of `$request->get('pid')`

Comment: The error message is thrown by the database - so what have you tried to check why the database is not receiving the value?

Comment: Dear @sta Thank you for answering me. I tried your code but I got same error.

Comment: Dear @Nico Haase Thank you for answering me. I see... I will check for database could I have some time I will look for it. Thank you again.

Comment: You might want to expand your validation because you want to prevent the SQL errors everywhere. So simply add `pid` to the required parameters. Also note that your `Contact::create()` function is potentially unsafe, since you are passing -everything- from the request to this function. This means that if there would be a hypothetical `is_admin` attribute on this model, you could simply pass it to this controller. The validation does not disallow such parameters to be sent.

Comment: Dear @Nico Haase I checked db connection. You are right! my Contact.php code is totally wrong. Thank you. I fixed that. but I still can't receive pid value. I post dd result.

Comment: Dear @Flame Thank you for answering me. I thought If I use Laravel framework all value are safe! you mean I should validation pid also? but There are posibility some url are doesn't have pid parameter value. so What do you recommend?

Comment: well to be more precise the values that are allowed to be passed to `create()` are defined in your model, see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`pid` is a query parameter and `pid`is not include in `$request->all()`, thats why SQL throw this error, change :

```
$data = request()->all();
$data['pid'] = $request->pid ?? 'default value'; // give a default value if pid is null
Contact::create($data);
```

Comment: Dear @sta Thank you very much for code. but I still can't receive pid value. I can get 'default value' . I tried to erase 2nd line. and tried again. I post 2 dd result. Could you look that please?

Comment: @bluetail did you added `pid` on your `Contact` model **fillable[...]** property?

Comment: Dear @sta Yes I did. I double checked it also.

Comment: @bluetail can you access it with `$_GET['pid'];` ?

Comment: Dear @sta Sorry I can't follow what you said. Where should I write$_GET['pid']; and check ?

Comment: `$_GET['pid'];` instead of  `$request->pid;`, if not work, then try with `$request->get('pid');`

Comment: Dear @sta Thank you. I tried your code. but same. I always get 'default value'.

Comment: This is strange, this problem is not related with given code. Maybe apache or nginx would be an issue

Comment: Dear @sta. Sorry for late reply. No. I didn't solve it. as I mentioned I have another program that I can get pid value. I add a js script to it then it didn't work. so I will re-create once again. Can I have some time I will report you after that.

Comment: what kind of server you are using?

Comment: Dear @sta I use rental server which is Apache/2.4.46. And Sorry. I'm still working on re-building this project I will contact you when it's done.

Comment: Dear @sta I rebuild project and it worked! Thank you so much for talking time for me. I don't know the reason of cause. but I'm guessing  that I had @ php ~ @ endphp at blade file that made problem. I'm not sure but seems like I rewrite it then fixed. Thank you again!

Comment: Dear @sta You've been helping my laravel problem many times. I really appreciate. Thank you very much.